# Mercurial branch confusion

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

This is the state of my repository. The working branch is stable.

[image]

I've pushed this repository to bitbucket. But when I clone from that bitbucket repository, the stable branch isn't selected as working branch. I have to update it to stable. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Which branch were you on when you pushed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial will always update to the latest change in the `default` branch when you clone a repository with no arguments.  If you don't have a `default` branch then you'll basically get a random branch when you clone.  This is documented [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching#What_not_to_do).

You can change this behaviour by adding the `-u branchname` command option to the clone command.

When you say 'working branch' what do you mean?  Do you mean that the main development work is done here?  `stable` isn't usually used as the main development branch because the name suggests that the code in that branch is stable which is not usually the case during development.  Normally, you would only make bug fixes on the `stable` branch.

There are three solutions to your problem as I see it:

1. continue updating to the correct branch when you create a new clone
2. clone using the `-u stable` option to update to the correct branch on clone
3. change the layout of the repository so that the `default` branch contains the code that you want people to work on most often after a clone

The advice on the Mercurial wiki that I linked to above would suggest that you go with option 3 but that is obviously more work.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the 'stable' branch is set as the main branch in the 'Repository details' setting page. Whatever is set here is the branch that you'll be on by default when you clone a fresh copy of the repository.

**EDIT:** As Steve points out below this only sets the default branch for the Bitbucket UI, not the HG client itself.

[image: Repository details]

Comment: That doesn't work.  Mercurial updates to the `default` branch on clone.  The `Main branch` setting of bitbucket seems to change the branch which is selected by default in the bitbucket repository pages.  It doesn't affect which branch is updated to on clone.